# How to make Chrome load PDF-file tabs, even if they are not selected?

Tags: google-chrome

In previous versions of Chrome, I could right click on a link to a PDF-file, select "Open Link in New Tab", and that tab would start loading immediately. I liked this behavior, because I could Command-click on PDF files that I knew would take a long time to load, finish reading the tab I was on, then switch tabs and – voila! – the 15 MB pdf file that I clicked on 2 minutes previously would be completely loaded.

But now Chrome only loads the PDF file once you actually look at the tab. So, I when I finally switch tabs, I need to wait for it to load.

Can I change this behavior?

Basically, I am looking for the opposite of this question: [How to Make Chrome Not Load Tabs Until They are Selected?](https://superuser.com/questions/811965/how-to-make-chrome-not-load-tabs-until-they-are-selected)

If you want to test this behavior, why not check out the latest PDF files about atomic physics: http://arxiv.org/list/physics.atom-ph/new

EDIT: This is similar to this question, but specific to tabs containing PDF files: [Google Chrome background tabs don't load/build until selected](https://superuser.com/questions/779021/google-chrome-background-tabs-dont-load-build-until-selected?rq=1).

EDIT: Realized that this is specific for PDF files. Changed title.

Comment: I suspect this is related to the new PDF viewer that showed up in Chrome 47 (the more obvious differences are the toolbar at the top and icons in the lower right corner).

Comment: Yes, I think that you are correct. The behavior change seems to have coincided with the cosmetic changes in the new PDF viewer.

Answer (score 0):

As per [google-chrome-background-tabs-dont-load-build-until-selected](https://superuser.com/questions/779021/google-chrome-background-tabs-dont-load-build-until-selected)
It seems that setting
`chrome://flags/#enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only`
to `disabled` does the trick for PDFs as well